# just in case VS. should

Tags: modal-verbs, conjunctions

> I'll be at my uncle's house **just in case** you need to reach me.
>
> I'll be at my uncle's house **should** you need to reach me.

Could you tell me what is the difference between those?

Comment: From Macmillan, **[in case](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/case#in-case)** (AmE) 1. if; 2. in order to be prepared for something that may happen; 3. used for explaining why you are doing something. Compared to [the same entry, but in BrE](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/case#in-case): 1. in order to be prepared for something that may happen; 2. used for explaining why you are doing something; 3. [mainly American] if. Isn't that interesting?

Answer (score 1):

In the **given context**, there's no difference. They mean the same.

> ['just in case'](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/just+in+case) is the idiom used to mean -*in the event that (something happens)* i.e. *in that condition*

*should* is also used as ***'if'*** and thus, this word too talks about the condition -in the event that/if something happens.

> [should](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=should) -expresses a condition i.e. just in case!

Comment: I would read "just in case" as implying an event less likely than the one referenced by "should". Just my personal feeling though.

Comment: @IanF1 'Should' works that way as well. *Just in case if you have a query, contact us* **=** *Should you have any query, contact us.* -for example.

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, your ideas have yet to present a more detailed and accurate answer or explanation, because one of my friend adviced to me""'Should' just expresses that the possibility of happening is more remote."

Comment: Even in official emails where an *instant* reply is expected, we put *should*. It simply means that *should* works for 'the near future' as well! :)

Comment: would you give me an example as ti the statement above?

Comment: And, would you show me usages of the verb  should in conditional type 2 and third

Answer (score 0):

But of course there is a difference but not in answering but in asking. :)
Let me alter the sentences somewhat to clarify meaning.
In case: I go to my uncle's house anyway - so I'll be there if you need me and I'll be there if you do not.
If: I stay here but will go to my uncle's house when and only when you need me, and if you don't need me then I remain at home..