# just in case VS. should you

Tags: conjunctions

> - I'll be at my uncle's house **just in case** you need to reach me.
> - I'll be at my uncle's house **should** you need to reach me.

Could you tell me what is the difference between those?

[enter link description here](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/7782990737?r=5092990737#5092990737)

Comment: is this not identical to http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44776/just-in-case-vs-should?

Answer (score 0):

"Just in case you need to" is colloquial in American English, and "should you need to" is somewhat formal, but they mean content-wise much the same thing: if some situation should arise where you need to be reached, you can be reached at your uncle's house.

In American English "just in case" can imply that the possibility is considered unlikely, but it's better to be safe than sorry:

**I will bring a flashlight just in case the light bulb in the basement is burnt out.**

If you remove the "just", the possibility is perceived to be more likely:

**I will bring a flashlight in case the light bulb in the basement is burnt out.**

Answer (score 0):

They *can* have a slightly different meaning:

> I'll be at my uncle's house **should** you need to reach me.

- Gives *only* an information about the place where you will spend a certain amount of time and where you can be contacted.

> I'll be at my uncle's house **just in case** you need to reach me.

- Can have the same meaning as above *or*
- state that you will be going to a certain place *with the purpose* to be available should the need arise.

Usually they are rather interchangeable.